# ImageField url returns an empty string

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add pictures to my Django web app. I have a model in my models.py which that looks something like this:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Protese(models.Model):
    '''Proteses usadas no High Five'''

    # Parte independente da lingua
    Nome = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Autores = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    AutoresURL = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Foto = models.ImageField()
    Data = models.DateTimeField()

    # Portugues
    Descricao = models.TextField()
    # Ingles
    Description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nome

class Membro(models.Model):
    '''Membros do projeto'''

    # Parte independente da lingua
    Nome = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Foto = models.ImageField()
    LinkedIn = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    # Portugues
    Posicao = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Frase = models.TextField()
    # Ingles
    Position = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Quote = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nome


class FeaturedImage(models.Model):
    ''' Imagem que aparece no comeco da pagina principal'''
    Image = models.FileField()
    # Portugues
    Titulo = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Texto = models.TextField()
    # Ingles
    Title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Text = models.TextField()

class Post(models.Model):
    ''' Posts de noticias '''
    Imagem = models.ImageField()
    # pt
    Titulo = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Texto = models.TextField()
    # en
    Title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Text = models.TextField()
```

For my settings.py I have the following code:

```
# settings.py
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and for my urls.py I have the following:

```
# urls.py

from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import url
import django.contrib.auth.views

import app.models as models
import app.views as views

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # Pagina principal
    url(r'^$',views.index,kwargs = {'lang':'pt'} ,name = 'index'),
    url(r'^index.html$',views.index,kwargs = {'lang':'pt'} ,name = 'index'),
    url(r'^en/$',views.index,kwargs = {'lang':'en'} ,name = 'index'),
    url(r'^en/index.html$',views.index,kwargs = {'lang':'en'} ,name = 'index'),
    # Sobre nos
    url(r'^about.html$',views.about, name = 'about'),
    # Servicos
    url(r'^services.html$',views.services, name = 'about'),
    # Contato
    url(r'^contact.html$',views.contact, name = 'about'),
    # Proteses
    url(r'^single/(?P<page_name>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/$',views.single, name='single'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am rendering my view using the following views.py function:

```
# views.py
def index(request, lang):
    context = {
        'featured_images':FeaturedImage.objects.all(),
        'proteses': Protese.objects.all(),
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
        'lang': lang
        }
    return render(request, 'web/index.html',context)
```

but then on my template when I try to get the image URL by typing:

```
            <ul class="slides">
                  {% for image in featured_images %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="banner-bottom" style="background: url( {{ image.Imagem.url }} )no-repeat center;">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="bann-text">
                                    {% if lang == 'pt' %}
                                        <h3> {{image.Titulo}} </h3>
                                        <p>{{image.Texto}}</p>
                                        <p>{{image.Imagem}}</p>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <h3> {{image.Title}} </h3>
                                        <p>{{image.Text}}</p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>              
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </li>
                  {% endfor %}                
                </ul>
```

I have the title showing up but the image doesn't show up. When I check the page's source code I have the image tag appering as:

```
<div class="banner-bottom" style="background: url()no-repeat center;">
```

Any idea on why this is happening?
Here is the output from the database when I run:

```
--dbshell
select * from app_foo;
1|Lorem Ipsum|At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos|Lore Ipsum|Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error|1.png
```

Where the latin dummy code is part os the other things in my model

Comment: Does foo have a value set for the image in the database?

Comment: Yes, I created a foo object where I uploaded an Image and I'm trying to display it

Comment: Can you please post the values in the database?

Comment: I'm sorry for the noob question but how do I do that?

Comment: From your shell: `python manage.py dbshell`; in the dbshell you can use the following command:  `select * from appname_foo` and paste the output.  `appname` should be changed to the name of your app.

Comment: Ok, sorry for taking so long, just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:  after seeing the your original files, this looks like a much simpler problem.

On your `FeaturedImage` model, you have an `Image` field, not an `Imagem` field.  I don’t know if that was a typo or not, but if that was pasted correctly, that would be the source of an issue.

i.e., you should try:

```
<div class="banner-bottom" style="background: url( {{ image.Image.url }} )no-repeat center;">
```

`Imagem` is a field on your `Post` model, and that may have been the source of the confusion.

---

Your view looks like it couldn’t possibly work, so there may be an issue if this is the actual view file:

```
# views.py
def renderFoo(request):
    # The below would give you a syntax error
    context = {
        'foos' = foo.objects.all(),
        ''' other models here '''
    }
    # You should be using:
    context = {
        'foos': foo.objects.all(),
        # other models here
    }
    return render(request,'path/to/page.html',context)
```

And it should work properly.  Accessing the `url` field like you are in the view is [the proper way to access the image URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/files/#using-files-in-models).

> ```
> >>> car = Car.objects.get(name="57 Chevy")
> >>> car.photo
> <ImageFieldFile: chevy.jpg>
> >>> car.photo.name
> 'cars/chevy.jpg'
> >>> car.photo.path
> '/media/cars/chevy.jpg'
> >>> car.photo.url
> 'http://media.example.com/cars/chevy.jpg'
> ```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the stack overflow, that is not the actual view file, in the view file it is 'foos': foo.objects.all() I will post the original one, it will probably make it easier to see the error. The thing is, I can reference the rest of the content on my template is just the image that doesn't work

Comment: Just posted the original files does that help?